# Cesium js. How Draw line binding a label to a position

Tags: label, line, pixel, offset, cesiumjs

I would like to draw a line binding a entity to its label with an offset.
CesiumJS allows to offset the label, however its not possible to draw a line (or polyline) from a position to an offset like the red line in this image.

[image]

How can i do it? any sugestion?

i'm using pixel offset. but there is no problem to use eye offset

```
 labels.add({
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 29.9522222),
        text: 'Another label',
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(100,-100)

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably a billboard with an image of the line on it. The length will never change if it's a pixelOffset. You can put an image of a white line, and use the color property to set any other color.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false, animation: false, timeline: false,
    // These next 6 lines are just to avoid Stack Snippet error messages.
    imageryProvider : new Cesium.TileMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url: Cesium.buildModuleUrl("Assets/Textures/NaturalEarthII"),
    }),
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    geocoder : false,
    infoBox : false
});

var scene = viewer.scene;
var offsetX = 50, offsetY = -80;
var pos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 29.9522222);

var labels = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.LabelCollection());
labels.add({
    position: pos,
    text: 'Another label',
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(offsetX, offsetY)
});

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = Math.abs(offsetX);
canvas.height = Math.abs(offsetY);
var context2D = canvas.getContext('2d');
context2D.beginPath();
context2D.lineWidth = 3;
context2D.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
context2D.moveTo((offsetX < 0) ? -offsetX : 0, (offsetY < 0) ? -offsetY : 0);
context2D.lineTo((offsetX < 0) ? 0 : offsetX, (offsetY < 0) ? 0 : offsetY);
context2D.stroke();

var billboards = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.BillboardCollection());

var billboard = billboards.add({
    color : Cesium.Color.RED,
    image : canvas,
    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(offsetX * 0.5, offsetY * 0.5),
    position : pos
});
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.78/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.78/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: the billboard image is a good solution, however i need a dynamic line. It's a pixel offset that can change if needed. The user may 'drag' the label to avoid label overlapping. that is why i need a line, not an image.

Comment: An option there is to draw the line onto a 2D canvas, and use the canvas image as the billboard.  This is how we used to draw points, and the code may still be hanging around in the "development" sandcastle demos someplace.

Comment: Oh, here's the canvas code:  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/b28/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Billboards.html#L224-L245

Comment: Thanks , much better.